# Assigning CORBA::WChar* to wchar_t* and sth more

Tags: c++, type-conversion, variable-assignment, corba, wchar-t

I know I recently created similar topic but now my question is a little bit different.

Is it legal to do this:

1)

```
CORBA::WString_var value;
const ::CORBA::WChar* v = L"ąśżźćłóń";
value = CORBA::wstring_dup(value);
```

2)

```
class WCharStuff
{
    private:
        CORBA::WString_var value;
    public:
        void setVal(const ::CORBA::WChar* val)
        {
            this->value = CORBA::wstring_dup(value);
        }
        ::CORBA::WChar* getVal()
        {
            return CORBA::wstring_dup(this->value.in());
        }
};

WCharStuff obj;
const wchar_t *v = L"ąśżźćłóń";
obj.setVal(v);
```

3)

```
class WCharStuff
{
    private:
        CORBA::WString_var value;
    public:
        void setVal(const wchar_t* val)
        {
            this->value = CORBA::wstring_dup(val);
        }
        ::CORBA::WChar* getVal()
        {
            return CORBA::wstring_dup(this->value.in());
        }
};

WCharStuff obj;
CORBA::WChar* v = L"ąśżźćłóń";
obj.setVal(v);
```

Will everything be ok that way (any memory leaks, etc.)? I use wide strings because 
I need **only** those characters: ąśżźćłóńę and ĄŚŻŹĆŁÓŃĘ.

Comment: looks good. haven't you tried it yourself?